# Workflow cannot update list item

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, permissions, designer-workflow

I have a workflow in sharepoint online. And it's workflow can do any things with current item and create task in association task list, but when i want update item in current list, my workflow nothing doing with item and continue working(hangs). Maybe sharepoint have some permission to allow this action ? Or you know another way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The workflow is connected in item update? The item you are trying ti change is the same item that the workflow is running?

Comment: @XristosK Workflow connected to documents library. Workflow start when item is changed. Item which not updates is not same item which started workflow.